# Can sets be implemented with linear probing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashmap, set

I'm trying to implement a `set` in Python with linear probing and think this is not optimal.

For example, supposed `2` and `88` hashes to the same hash key, resulting in a collision.

1. insert `88`. success
2. insert `2`. collides with `88`, probe to another address and insert. success
3. delete `88` and marking that hash key as `tombstone`. success
4. insert `2`. replace `tombstone` to `2`. success

However for a set, the 4th step should not succeed as the HT now has 2 of the same keys.

Removing `2` from the set will then require a linear scan to ensure all instances of `2`s are removed, which defeats the purpose of using set for `O(1)` lookup.

Is the solution to use separate chaining for resolving hash collisions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can use linear probing for a map, you can use it for a set: a set is effectively a map to nothing; or alternatively a map is a set of keys, each of which has an associated value.   Your problem is that your "tombstone" loses the fact that there are other entries in the same bucket.  It needs to point to the remainder of the logical chain that is this bucket.  A separate "deleted" flag should do it.  Special treatment of deletion of the last in the chain would be useful.

Comment: Not all sets need to implement deletion, by the way.